# HSQL - identify number of open connection

Tags: java, hsqldb

I'm using embedded HSQL database server. Is there any way to identify number of open connection alive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_SESSIONS
```